# Explicit UpdateSource on element with LostFocus trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, updatesourcetrigger

My Scenario is, upon opening application, I read lots of data from file (using `XMLSerializer`) and put it into `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`. Using Bindings, I present data to users. When they change data in a field, proper data in collection is updated, but I don't want that data to be saved to file upon `LostFocus`. I have a button 'SAVE'.

I don't want to use `UpdateSOurceTrigger = PropertyChanged`, I want to keep `LostFocus`. The problem is, when user enters data to a `TextBox` and presses Save button, `TextBox` does not loses focus, meaning data is not propagated to collection and is not saved. Below is my solution that works, yet, my question is, Is it a proper way of doing, or is there other, better way?

The code I added to Save button, before saving collection:

```
IInputElement focusedElement = Keyboard.FocusedElement;

if (focusedElement is TextBox)
{
    BindingExpression myBinding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression((TextBox)focusedElement, TextBox.TextProperty);
    myBinding.UpdateSource();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of your scenario:

```
<Window x:Class="MementoAndLostFocus.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MementoAndLostFocus"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ExampleInstance.ExampleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
             BorderThickness="1"
             BorderBrush="Black"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Margin="10"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Content="Save"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ExampleClass ExampleInstance { get; set; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ExampleInstance = new ExampleClass() { ExampleName = "Example Name" };
        SaveCommand = new SaveCommand(this);
    }

    internal void Save()
    {
        //TO DO  - Save item to database
        Console.WriteLine(ExampleInstance.ExampleName);
    }
}

public class ExampleClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _exampleName;

    public string ExampleName
    {
        get { return _exampleName; }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ExampleName)));
            _exampleName = value;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}

public class SaveCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainViewModel _vm;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public SaveCommand(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _vm.Save();
    }
}
```

So what exactly is going on here:

As you see, the `TextBox` is there and its `UpdateSourceTrigger` is set to `LostFocus`.

When I modify the value there and click Save button, I am able to see what happens, with a break point in the Save method and the value is updated, because when you **click the button**, the `TextBox` loses the focus.

[image]

[image]

Anyway i wanted to write this to you because there could be something more.

Have a look at `IEditableObject` interface :

> Provides functionality to commit or rollback changes to an object that
>   is used as a data source.

That's about it.